# SapUI5 Popover arrow is not pointing to dependent element which is clicked after setting the offsetY

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, popover

I am using **sap.m.Popover** and i have a button and made that button as a dependent element for that popover.Now if i set the *offsetY* to that popover the popover is moving according to the *offsetY* value but the arrow that was pointing to the dependent element will be moved and it will not be pointing to that element also.How to make popover pointer to pointing to dependent element even after adding *offsetY* ?

[image]

Comment: You mean, the pointer should stay sticked to the button so that it gets stretched by the value of `offsetY`? What's the context btw? Why do you need to change the offset in the first place? Is the popover hiding something?

Comment: @boghyon yes,i have a table in bottom half of the page and in top part of page the button is there in the middle part of top half.So once i open the popover the popover is opening like half part goes to top half and remaining half part of popover goes to botton half of the page..so in order to avoid overlapping i have to set offset and move it to top half.But the pointer is also moving.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In that case, wouldn't it make sense to just change the [`placement`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Popover/methods/setPlacement) (instead of `offsetY`) e.g. to [`"Top"`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.PlacementType)? Then the popover wouldn't cross the bottom half of the page.

Comment: @boghyon I have updated the question so if i use placement as top the remaining buttons will be blocked.So i have to move the popover by keeping the placement as right.But if i apply offsetY then the arrow will also move up and its no longer pointing to same source.

Comment: I see. This looks like a reasonable enhancement request to post on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues). Give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071776/sapui5-popover-arrow-is-not-pointing-to-dependent-element-which-is-clicked-after/#comment83167464_48071776) solution of @boghyon in the comments of the question: change the placement of the Popover to `placement="Top"`

If changing the placement is not an option use the original solution of mine which is NOT recommended as it use a private method and direct CSS manipulation but for the moment it's the only one:

The Popover component itself doesn't offer any method to set offsetY of the arrow element. 
The arrow can be repositioned with the [_afterAdjustPositionAndArrowHook](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html#_afterAdjustPositionAndArrowHook):

> Hook called after adjusment of the Popover position.

To do so, after instantiate the popover fragment in Controller event handler function add [_afterAdjustPositionAndArrowHook](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html#_afterAdjustPositionAndArrowHook) to the popover and reposition the arrow: (I assume `placement="Right"` because of offsetY)

```
var self = this;
this._oPopover =
    sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.m.sample.Popover.Popover", this);

this._oPopover._afterAdjustPositionAndArrowHook = function() {
    var arrow = jQuery('#myPop-arrow');
    arrow.css('top', Math.max(21, parseInt(arrow.css('top')) -
        self._oPopover.getOffsetY()));
};

this.getView().addDependent(this._oPopover);
```

View:

```
<Popover id="myPop" placement="Right" offsetY="100" ...>
```

Based on the [Popover Sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Popover/code/C.controller.js)